# How can I create/delete a table row with form controls using AJAX?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, c#-3.0

I have a table that has several fixed rows that contain user controls that have their own Update panels. I need to be able to create new rows within this table, each column of which contains a TextBox control. I don't want to just wrap the whole table in an Update Panel for obvious reasons, but want to be able to create/delete the new row(s) without a full postback and have the TextBox controls registered/de-registered to/from the page, without having to rebuild the entire table.

Any ideas how/if this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done using a client-side approach, such as building the UI with JavaScript templating or an MVVM framework.  You could also use a ListView that can be easily templated to render the initial shell, and additional rows can be added with JavaScript.

Or, wrap the whole table in one UpdatePanel.

Comment: I was hoping there might be a way of creating the additional row and textboxes using Javascript and then doing a partial postback just to register the controls on the page?

Comment: Any dynamic controls have to be added to the control tree on EVERY postback.  So on postback, you have to read the form values and generate the controls accordingly.

Comment: Could I generate the dynamic rows entirely client side using html textfields with unique IDs based on the lookup data record the row relates to and then inspect the POST data on postback. If I know there could be between 0-20 dynamic rows (based on lookup data that each row relates to) I could just loop through each record, see if a row exists for that record in POST data and process accordingly. Does that sound plausible/sensible?